# Including rotated label alongside stacked label in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, labeling, vbscript, rotate

I am trying to replicate the label that I have attached an image of.

Is this possible in ArcMap?

So far I have stacked 3 labels but am unsure how to:

1. Create 3 individual boxes around the stacked labels
2. Include the 4th label field and rotate at 90 degrees

This is my current expression:

```
[Code] &vbnewline& [Plot_Ref]&"_"& [Plot_ID] &vbnewline& [GRASS_Ref]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of combining multiple attributes in a single label, you can **Create Classes for each attribute** by changing the "method" Dropdown.

[image]

You can then position each label separately, including the angle property for the fourth attribute by going to "Label Settings"->"Properties"->"Symbol Properties"->"Edit Symbol"
[image]

As far as the boundary is concerned, I once did it by using a template empty boundary png as another class.